# How can I have 2 ADO access methods use the same Transaction?

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net, transactions

I'm writing a test to see if my LINQ to Entity statement works.. I'll be using this for others if I can get this concept going..

my intention here is to INSERT a record with ADO, then verify it can be queried with LINQ, and then ROLLBACK the whole thing at the end.

I'm using ADO to insert because I don't want to use the object or the entity model that I am testing. I figure that a plain ADO INSERT should do fine.

problem is.. they both use different types of connections.

**is it possible to have these 2 different data access methods use the same TRANSACTION so I can roll it back??**

```
_conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
_conn.Open();

_trans = _conn.BeginTransaction();

var x = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Table1(ID, LastName, FirstName, DateOfBirth) values('127', 'test2', 'user', '2-12-1939');", _conn);

x.ExecuteNonQuery();     //So far, so good.  Adding a record to the table.

//at this point, we need to do **_trans.Commit()** here because our Entity code can't use the same connection. Then I have to manually delete in the TestHarness.TearDown..  I'd like to eliminate this step


//(this code is in another object, I'll include it for brevity. Imagine that I passed the connection in)
//check to see if it is there
using (var ctx = new XEntities(_conn)) //can't do this.. _conn is not an EntityConnection! 
{
    var retVal = (from m in ctx.Table1
                  where m.first_name == "test2"
                  where m.last_name == "user"
                  where m.Date_of_Birth == "2-12-1939"
                  where m.ID == 127
                  select m).FirstOrDefault();

     return (retVal != null);
 }

//Do test.. Assert.BlahBlah();

_trans.Rollback();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand(v=VS.100).aspx

```
_conn = new EntityConnection(_connectionString);
EntityTransaction myTrans = _conn.BeginTransaction();

using(MyObjectContext x = new MyObjectContext(_conn))
{
  x.ExecuteStoreCommand(insertString);
}

CallTest(_conn)

myTrans.Rollback();
```

Of course, since you have an object context at that point, you don't have to use ExecuteStoreCommand if you'd instead prefer to new up a data instance, attach and save changes.

Comment: This is probably the best solution for my problem.  I was able to slap my INSERT statement into x.ExecuteStoreCommand() instead of using SqlCommand(). Luckily I was able to use the same connection string for both as they were located in the same database. Thanks for the excellent answer!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just use [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152%28VS.90%29.aspx):

```
using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope()) {
    // Do something in ADO.NET with one connection.

    // Do something with Linq in another connection

    // Commit (or not if you want to roll back)
    //ts.Complete();
}
```

No other explicit transaction handling is needed.  Note though that if you use two different connections, you will need to have DTC running.

Comment: What do you mean by "DTC running"?  is this a service?

Comment: This was also a really good answer, as it hit to the meat of my question.  I wound up not picking it due to some unknown security issue with DTC.  However, it makes total sense for the question I asked.

Comment: In my case I wasn't accessing 2 different databases, but this would be the correct answer if I were.

Comment: @KevinDeus - I mention DTC because it seems that sometimes even if you aren't using two databases (just two connections to the same database) it still wants to use DTC anyways.  At least that's been my experience.

Comment: Better would be to reuse the connection used by the ObjectContext. A Distributed Transaction should be avoided as long as possible. It would involve the DTC and performance-wise it's better avoided and I think in your case you can. It also depends on the version of SQL server you are using.
You can access it doing something like this ((EntityConnection)objectContext.Connection).StoreConnection;

Answer (score 0):

Here was my final test that I created based upon my selected answer.  I'm actually testing a service that makes a LINQ to Entities call to the database. (that LINQ you saw is basically what is in the WCF Service function)

This way I can call the service using the same connection I INSERTed with..  ( I could actually move the connection and transaction stuff to setup & teardown, but this is it in a nutshell)

```
   [Test]
    public void Test_VerifyXXX()
    {
        var _conn = new EntityConnection(_connectionString2);

        _conn.Open();
        EntityTransaction myTrans = _conn.BeginTransaction();

        using (var x = new XEntities(_conn))
        {
            x.ExecuteStoreCommand("INSERT INTO Table1(ID, LastName, FirstName, DateOfBirth) values('127', 'test2', 'user', '2-12-1939');");
        }             

        XService test = new XService_Mock(_conn);
        bool results = test.CustomerVerified(127, "user", "test2", new DateTime(1939, 2, 12));

        Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof(bool), results);
        Assert.AreEqual(true, results);

        myTrans.Rollback();
    }
```